# Laravel: hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wasted my whole day but cannot figure out hasManyThrough relationship.

I have this relationship:

```
# get related users
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, FuneralHomeUser::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

This generates me this query:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `funeral_homes_users`.`user_id`
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `funeral_homes_users` ON `funeral_homes_users`.`id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `funeral_homes_users`.`user_id` = '4'
```

Everything is good except for `ON funeral_homes_users.id = users.id` should be `ON funeral_homes_users.user_id = users.id`. So the only thing I am trying to get is instead of `id`, it should have `user_id` for `funeral_homes_users.id` (eg it should be `funeral_homes_users.user_id`) but I am unable to figure it out.

Here are tables for reference:

```
// funeral_homes
Schema::create('funeral_homes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// funeral_homes_users
Schema::create('funeral_homes_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('funeral_home_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});

// users
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password', 60);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: Are you sure you have hasManyThrough and not Many-to-Many relationship?

Comment: @naneri: Not sure, i am new to this, i have posted table structure, if this is the case, it is most welcome with help. Thanks

Comment: I suspect it is hasManyThrough because `funeral_homes` doesn't have a relation directly with users.

Comment: Can you post an example of calling the Funeral_homes model?

Comment: are you trying to get "funeral_homes" from "users"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your case is:

`USER` has many `FUNERAL_HOME`

`FUNERAL_HOME` belongs to many `USER`

if that is correct, your relation methods should return something like this:

`User.php`

```
public function FuneralHomes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(FuneralHome::class, 'funeral_homes_users');
}
```

---

`FuneralHome.php`

```
public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'funeral_homes_users');
}
```

Take look at the [doku](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: you are the hero!!!, thanks for your help, really appreciated, you saved me from wasting another day :)

Comment: glad, that could help :)